# Capture a video and store it at a specific location rather than a default location

Tags: android

I want to capture video and store video at specific location other than default location.

I know there is a method with MediaStore called `setOutPutFile("String Location")`.
But it is not working properly.

I have seen many examples and performed but it stores video in default location only. Can someone help me solve this problem?

Comment: I have rewritten and reformatted your question for you. Please have a good look at the differences. Full capitals, exclamation points, pleas and the like are not a good approach to a question.

Comment: hey Shoban i m not shouting ...!!
I want solution if anyone have..!!
Thats it..!!

Comment: Hey Bart thanks for this..!!
and sorry
I will be careful next time..!!

Answer (score 13):

Do in this way :

Globally declare it

```
public static final int TAKE_PICTURE=0;
```

and then

```
Intent photoPickerIntent= new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
                      startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(photoPickerIntent,"Take Video"),TAKE_VIDEO);
```

In OnActivityResult Handle in this way:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
         {
                if(requestCode==TAKE_VIDEO)
            {


                try
                {
                    Log.e("videopath","videopath");
                AssetFileDescriptor videoAsset = getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(data.getData(), "r");
                FileInputStream fis = videoAsset.createInputStream();
                File root=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"Directory Name");

                  if (!root.exists()) {
                      root.mkdirs();
                  }

                  File file;
                  file=new File(root,"android_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".mp4" );

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                int len;
                while ((len = fis.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    fos.write(buf, 0, len);
                }       
                fis.close();
                fos.close();
              } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
             }
        }
```

Use below permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
```

Comment: Hello... I tried your code but even it stores the video on its default location only..!! if you found other solution than help me to solve out this problem..!! Thanks..!!

Comment: did you give your directory name? check in that directory

Comment: @VaibhavVajani whats was the "other solution" ? please share.

Comment: You have forgot one more permission ie. <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: @MelbourneLopes   http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html

Comment: @Abhi  When I tried to run your code on my galexy nexus running android 4.1, The app crashed. So I put respected permission and It worked great. What i mean to say is, App crashes with version lower than API 19. So its necessory to add this permission for versions lower then API 19.

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't happy with any of the solutions provided here. Here's an extremely simple solution that will save the video in folder of your choice.

```
private static final int REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE = 300;
private Uri videoUri;

private void dispatchVideoIntent(){
    Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    File outputFile = new File("your file path goes here");
    videoUri = Uri.fromFile(outputFile);
    takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, videoUri);
    if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && videoUri != null) {
            // do what you want with videoUri
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by abhi here is correct, but i am writing a new answer to make it more easy and simple to other users.

To record a video, write this code in your `onCreate` method or on button click where you want to start the video recording

```
private static final int ACTION_TAKE_VIDEO = 3;

Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, ACTION_TAKE_VIDEO);
```

This code will start video recording.

Now below in your code after the `onCreate` method you need to override a method which name is  `onActivityResult`.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
    {
        try
        {
            AssetFileDescriptor videoAsset = getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(data.getData(), "r");
            FileInputStream fis = videoAsset.createInputStream();
            File root=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/RecordVideo/");  //you can replace RecordVideo by the specific folder where you want to save the video
            if (!root.exists()) {
                System.out.println("No directory");
                root.mkdirs();
            }

            File file;
            file=new File(root,"android_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".mp4" );

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = fis.read(buf)) > 0) {
                fos.write(buf, 0, len);
            }       
            fis.close();
            fos.close();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Replace "RecordVideo" with the specific folder where you want to the video file on your sd card. You can also use any existing folder or directory name here.

Thanks