# Saving camera api videos in internal storage directory

Tags: android, camera-api

I am building an app which  **record videos** with *camera API*. I followed a tutorial from android developers site after the video records, It is saved in an external storage directory. How do I save in i**nternal storage** instead of  external storage.

```
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;

    /** Create a file Uri for saving an image or video */
    private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
          return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }

    /** Create a File for saving an image or video */
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
        // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
        // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
          Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");
        // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
        // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.


        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
        Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
        return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
       if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
    "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }
```

Comment: Start with looking into the documentation for the `Environment` class. The snippet you posted references `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
          Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)`, try to figure out how to change this to a reference to the internal storage.

Comment: This might help you check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033710/capture-a-video-and-store-it-at-a-specific-location-rather-than-a-default-locati)

Answer (score 0):

All you need is in the official android dev site: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal fixed